# Размер класса в определенной иерархии

Tags: c++, наследование, множественное-наследование

Почему объект класса `A` занимает 4 байта?

```
#include <iostream>


struct F {};

struct D: F {};

struct E: F {};

struct B: D, E {};

struct C: D, E {};

struct A: B, C {};


int main() {
    std::cout << sizeof(A{}) << '\n';
}
```

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ebo

Comment: @HolyBlackCat сокращение доставляет маленько

Comment: Правильный ответ 4 но у msvc очередной баг и выводит 3

Answer (score 2):

Правило "оптимизации пустых базовых классов" (empty base optimization) позволяет пустым базовым подобъектам иметь размер 0 в составе объекта-наследника. Однако в то же время два различных базовых подобъекта одного и того же типа обязаны иметь разные адреса, даже если они пусты. У вас в вашей иерархии в классе `A` набирается как минимум `4` различных базовых подобъекта типа `F`. Это уже требует размера как минимум в `4` минимальных адресуемых единицы памяти.

Если сделать

```
int main() 
{
  A a;
  std::cout << sizeof a << std::endl;
  std::cout << &a << std::endl;
  std::cout << (F *)(D *)(B *) &a << std::endl;
  std::cout << (F *)(E *)(B *) &a << std::endl;
  std::cout << (F *)(D *)(C *) &a << std::endl;
  std::cout << (F *)(E *)(C *) &a << std::endl;
}
```

то получаем (GCC, Clang)

```
4
0x7ffcc5ed5f5c
0x7ffcc5ed5f5c
0x7ffcc5ed5f5d
0x7ffcc5ed5f5e
0x7ffcc5ed5f5f
```

MSVC++, похоже, полагает, что для последнего (по порядку в памяти) подобъекта `F` нужен лишь уникальный адрес, но не нужно фактического байта памяти, по каковой причине размер `A` получается равным `3`. Это нехорошо, ведь какой-то другой - внешний по отношению к `A` - объект может разместиться по тому же адресу, что и последнее `F` в `A`.

Проверим

```
struct X
{
  A a;
  char c;
};

int main() 
{
  X a; 
  std::cout << sizeof a << std::endl;
  std::cout << &a << std::endl;
  std::cout << (F *)(D *)(B *) &a.a << std::endl;
  std::cout << (F *)(E *)(B *) &a.a << std::endl;
  std::cout << (F *)(D *)(C *) &a.a << std::endl;
  std::cout << (F *)(E *)(C *) &a.a << std::endl;
  std::cout << (void *) &a.c << std::endl;
}
```

получаем

```
3
000000B30CEFFA44
000000B30CEFFA44
000000B30CEFFA45
000000B30CEFFA46
000000B30CEFFA47
000000B30CEFFA47
```

Если я не ошибаюсь, совпадение адресов `(F *)(E *)(C *) &a.a` и `&a.c` является нарушением требований спецификации языка, т.е. багом в MSVC++.

Answer (score 0):

В C++ стандарте размер структуры должен иметь минимум один байт.

> 1.8 The C ++ object model
>
> Unless it is a bit-field (9.6), a most derived object shall have a
>   non-zero size and shall occupy one or more bytes of storage. Base
>   class subobjects may have zero size. An object of trivially copyable
>   or standard-layout type (3.9) shall occupy contiguous bytes of
>   storage.

Структура **F** имеет размер один байт. **D** = **F** + 0 = 1 . **B** = **D** + **E** = 1 + 1 = 2 . **A** = **B** + **C** = 2 + 2 = 4 .

Comment: Ну, у меня выдало результат в три байта:)

Comment: Хорошо бы еще рассказать, почему родители `D`,`E` и `B`,`C` не накладываются друг на друга. А то по такому ответу непонятно, почему в примере из вопроса 4, а [вот тут](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8126eb3444b94eb6) - 2.

Comment: @LexMarchenko На каком компиляторе?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, msvc2019.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat действительно странная [тройка](https://rextester.com/OVC3593), особенно учитывая, что в выводе 4 разных адреса.